# Generating function for 'inversions' in max-heap

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Problem from an old exam:

> A full binary tree of height $n$ has $2^n-1$ vertices. We randomly insert all numbers $1, \ldots, 2^n-1$ into it (each permutation is equally likely). An error is defined as a pair of vertices $(v, w)$ such that $v$ is the ancestor of $w$, but the value in $v$ is smaller than the value in $w$ (we want a max-heap). Let $X$ be a random variable indicating the number of errors.

> Find the generating function of the probability distribution of the random variable $X, g_X(t)$. It is sufficient to give the answer in the form of a product of expressions in a compact form.

Where should I start solving this problem? I have seen similar problem before and it was solved using recurrence relation. Also, Shouldn't $n$ be specified in order to be able to find that generating function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q_n$ be  the generating function in $x$  that we seek
where the  exponent gives  the number  of inversions  in a
full binary heap  on $2^n-1$ nodes. We have $Q_1  = 1$. On
the other hand for the  recursion we must first choose the
top node  from among the $2^n-1$  possibilities and choose
the   labels   that  go   onto   the   left  subtree   for
${2^n-2\choose   2^{n-1}-1}$   possibilities,   with   the
remaining labels going to the  right subtree. With the top
node  $k$ it  will  clearly  produce $2^n-1-k$  additional
inversions as we  are asking for a max-heap.  We label the
subtrees respecting  the ordering  of nodes in  the source
trees, same  as when we  do the labeling of  the cartesian
product  of  two   exponential  generating  functions  for
combinatorial classes.  Here we  have an OGF however. This
gives the recurrence

$$Q_n = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1} x^{2^n-1-k} 
{2^n-2\choose 2^{n-1}-1} Q_{n-1}^2$$

or alternatively

$$Q_n = Q_{n-1}^2 {2^n-2\choose 2^{n-1}-1} 
\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-2} x^{k}.$$

E.g. we have

$$Q_3  = 80  x^{10}+240 x^{9}+480  x^{8}+640 x^{7}+720
x^{6} \\ +720  x^{5}+720 x^{4}+640 x^{3}+480 x^{2}+240
x +80.$$

Look  it up  in the  OEIS to  get a  pointer to  [OEIS
A306393](https://oeis.org/A306393),  where  more  data
awaits.

**Remark.** We  can actually  unroll the  recursion to
get

$$Q_n = \prod_{q=0}^{n-1}
\left[\frac{1-x^{2^{n-q}-1}}{1-x}\right]^{2^q}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1}
{2^{n-q}-2\choose 2^{n-q-1}-1}^{2^q}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2^n-1}}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1}
{2^{n-q}-2\choose 2^{n-q-1}-1}^{2^q}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1}
\left[1-x^{2^{n-q}-1}\right]^{2^q}.}$$

**Observation.**  We get  for  the  average number  of
inversions that it is given by

$$\frac{1}{(2^n-1)!}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1}
{2^{n-q}-2\choose 2^{n-q-1}-1}^{2^q}
\left.
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1} [1+\cdots+x^{2^{n-q}-2}]^{2^q}
\\ \times \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} 2^q
\frac{1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+(2^{n-q}-2)x^{2^{n-q}-3}}
{1+\cdots+x^{2^{n-q}-2}}
\right|_{x=1}
\\ = \frac{1}{(2^n-1)!}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1}
{2^{n-q}-2\choose 2^{n-q-1}-1}^{2^q}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1} [2^{n-q}-1]^{2^q}
\\ \times \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} 2^{q-1}
\frac{(2^{n-q}-2)(2^{n-q}-1)}{2^{n-q}-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{(2^n-1)!}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1}
{2^{n-q}-2\choose 2^{n-q-1}-1}^{2^q}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1} [2^{n-q}-1]^{2^q}
\\ \times \sum_{q=0}^{n-1}
(2^{n-1}-2^q).$$

We have for the product terms

$$\frac{1}{(2^n-1)!} \prod_{q=1}^{n}
\frac{(2^{n+1-q}-2)!^{2^{q-1}}}{(2^{n-q}-1)!^{2^{q}}}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-1} [2^{n-q}-1]^{2^q}
\\ = \frac{1}{(2^n-2)!} \prod_{q=1}^{n}
\frac{(2^{n+1-q}-2)!^{2^{q-1}}}{(2^{n-q}-1)!^{2^{q}}}
\prod_{q=1}^{n-1} [2^{n-q}-1]^{2^q}
\\ = \frac{1}{(2^n-2)!} \prod_{q=1}^{n-1}
\frac{(2^{n+1-q}-2)!^{2^{q-1}}}{(2^{n-q}-1)!^{2^{q}}}
\prod_{q=1}^{n-1} [2^{n-q}-1]^{2^q}
\\ = \frac{1}{(2^n-2)!} \prod_{q=1}^{n-1}
\frac{(2^{n-(q-1)}-2)!^{2^{q-1}}}{(2^{n-q}-2)!^{2^{q}}}
\\ = \frac{1}{(2^n-2)!} \prod_{q=1}^{n-1}
\frac{(2^{q+1}-2)!^{2^{n-q-1}}}{(2^{q}-2)!^{2^{n-q}}}
= 1.$$

This leaves just the sum term, producing

$$2^{n-1} \times n - (2^n-1)$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
2^{n-1} \times (n-2) + 1.}$$

In terms of the number $m$  of nodes we get on average
$O(m \times \log m)$ inversions.

Comment: For the "With the top node $k$ it will clearly produce $k−1$ additional inversions," shouldn't it be $2^n - 1 - k$ instead, since that's the number of larger numbers that will be in the subtrees? Although the result will be the same so I guess it doesn't really matter. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, correction made.